# Expressions in a querybuildRange

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Hi I am trying to do this query:

```
Select ProjInvoiceJour 
where NOT (ProjInvoiceJour.ProjInvoiceType == ProjInvoiceType::Onaccount && ProjInvoiceJour.CountryRegionID != "ES")
```

But I need to do it whit querybuilder:

```
qbds.addRange(fieldnum(ProjInvoiceJour, ProjInvoiceType)).value(strfmt('!%1',
                           strfmt("((%1.%2 == %3) && (%4.%5 != '%6'))",
                                    tablestr(ProjInvoiceJour),
                                    fieldstr(ProjInvoiceJour, ProjInvoiceType),
                                    any2int(ProjInvoiceType::OnAccount),
                                    tablestr(ProjInvoiceJour),
                                    fieldstr(ProjInvoiceJour, CountryRegionID),
                                    queryvalue("ES"))));
```

But the query has some error:

```
SELECT * FROM ProjInvoiceJour WHERE ((NOT (ProjInvoiceType = 255)))
```

Thanks

Comment: If you were to remove the strFmt portion and put it into a job by itself, what does it print out? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Can you please try changing single quotes in first strfmt to double quotes?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [law of De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) comes to rescue:

```
select ProjInvoiceJour 
    where !(ProjInvoiceJour.ProjInvoiceType == ProjInvoiceType::Onaccount && 
            ProjInvoiceJour.CountryRegionID != 'ES')
```

is equivalent to:

```
select ProjInvoiceJour 
    where ProjInvoiceJour.ProjInvoiceType != ProjInvoiceType::Onaccount ||
          ProjInvoiceJour.CountryRegionID == 'ES'
```

Or in a query:

```
qbds.addRange(fieldnum(ProjInvoiceJour, ProjInvoiceType)).value(strfmt('((%1.%2 != %3) || (%4.%5 == "%6"))',
                                tablestr(ProjInvoiceJour),
                                fieldstr(ProjInvoiceJour, ProjInvoiceType),
                                0+ProjInvoiceType::OnAccount,
                                tablestr(ProjInvoiceJour),
                                fieldstr(ProjInvoiceJour, CountryRegionID),
                                'ES'));
```

Comment: Quotes changed.